# Starting a .NET Application From CD?

Tags: .net, winpe, app-startup

we're trying to figure out a way to build a .NET application that can run entirely self contained from a CD.  Basically user pops in a CD, boots to an operating system on the CD and a barebones .NET Framework starts up with the application.  We've looked at hacking the .NET Framework into WinPE but realize it's really an unsupported hack. Has anyone tried anything like this and had any success?

Comment: Do you mean, on a machine which doesn't already have the .NET framework installed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You pretty much need to have the .NET framework installed on the machine for this to work.  If the correct framework is installed, this won't be an issue - just run the executable.

Tools like NGEN still require the framework to be installed.

However, there are some commercial tools, such as [PostBuild](http://www.xenocode.com/Products/Postbuild-for-NET/), that will go through and compile all of the required dependencies into native code.  In theory, this would provide your required behavior.

Comment: RemoteSoft has a compiler which does something similar (http://www.remotesoft.com/salamander/index.html).  If you cannot rely on an available .NET framework, this is a very good option.

Answer (score 3):

You could look at Mono, as they've got an embedable version of the framework which requires no .NET Framework (or Mono) to be installed. Can't tell you how much work that'll be, but take a look [here](http://www.mono-project.com/Embedding_Mono), it's documented and supported.

Answer (score 0):

I got lucky and found what your looking for:  http://www.monoppix.com/